# New blog post published notification - Buddypress

Tags: posts, buddypress

When I open a blog post, I want to send a notification to all members.

Normally, on the section of buddypress activity, it appears like ''admin wrote a new post, POSTNAME''

How do I integrate this into the buddypress notifications section.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a link-only answer, but this might help out. I was looking at this method the other day to try to solve a problem:

https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_notifications_add_notification/